# Deploying Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, hosting, apache-axis

I have made an Axis2 Web Service in Java. I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0.32 as a Web Server. My Web Service gets the data from the database(MySQL), and it returns the data into my mobile application. Now I want to deploy my Web Service. What are the steps for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link if you want to deploy without using eclipse

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/ws-webaxis1/

If you are using eclipse then

1. In preferences setup the Axis 2 runtime
2. Right click on the project where you have your service implementation & choose the New webservice option.  Use the Bottom Up Java Bean Web Service option

You can also quickly create a client to test it.